# How to export multiple classes from a single file?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Say I have a file called `participant.coffee`, with two classes in it:

```
class ParticipantData
     constructor: (data) ->
           # whatever

     doSomething:
          console.log 'participant data!'

class ParticipantResult
     doAnotherThing:
          console.log 'participant result!'

module.exports = new ParticipantResult()
```

Right now I can access `ParticipantResult` by using `require('.particpantresult')`, but I can't figure out any way to call `ParticipantData`'s constructor.  Is it possible to access `ParticipantData` without moving it to it's own file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return an object with the constructors, then call those:

```
module.exports = {
  ParticipantData: ParticipantData,
  ParticipantResult: ParticipantResult
};
```

with the class-using code:

```
var dm = require("...");
var myParticipantResult = new dm.ParticipantResult();
```